# Spring Boot Restful POST recognized as GET issue

Tags: rest, post, spring-boot, postman

I am using spring boot restful for my server side.   I am using Tomcat 8.0 to do the development

AppConfig.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.my.project, package com.my.project.db"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);
private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);     
    log.info("Application Start");
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.getServletRegistration(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
            .setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
}
```

Login.java

```
@CrossOrigin("*") 
@RestController
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<LoginInfo> doLogin(@RequestBody LoginInfo loginInfo) {

    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;

    if (loginInfo.getLogin() == null || loginInfo.getPassword() == null) {
        // error;
        status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        log.error("login or password is empty.");
    }

    return RestAPIUtils.responseEntity(loginInfo, "/login", status);    
}
```

I am using Postman to do the test. 
for Input, I choose "POST" method, and type in the url correctly, with 
headers: { Content-Type: 'application/json' }, and Body as follow:

```
{
    login: "myname",
    password: "password"
}
```

Then, I got an error as follow:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1480585504124,
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
  "path": "/myProject/login/"
}
```

I tried playing around with the Type to "PUT", and "DELETE", and the error did changed to 'PUT', or 'DELETE' accordingly.  Only POST is being recognized as 'GET'???

I even tried to change both the server side and postman to 'PUT' and I get the expected result with Http Code 200, OK:

```
{
    login: "myname",
    password: "password",
    status: "success"
}
```

what is wrong with the POST function, can anyone please help me?
Thanks so much!

Comment: could be the same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895072/request-method-post-not-supported-in-spring-4/40897462#40897462

Comment: OK, after some hours of testing, I figured it out that if I change the URL on Postman to "http://localhost:8080/myProject/login/" then it works.  The old path was "http://localhost:8080/myProject/login".  
Also, I tried to add some more words to the path, it works perfectly without needed the "/" at the end.  Though, I do not know why this is happening, and why all other method works perfectly with the simple "login" at the end.

Comment: You should answer your own question or delete it.

Comment: Thank Niekname, although the issue seems to be resolved, but I still do not understand the behavior.  I hope someone can answer my post.  The logic behind why the path needs a "/" at the end for POST method only?